# How do I enable desktop environment?

Tags: installation, 12.10, desktop-environments

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.10 and am able to successfully log in, but when I get to the desktop, it is blank. Terminal is functioning. Dell inspiron 710m, integrated intel graphics. I have tried `sudo apt-get install update` but I am faced with the response:

```
E: Unable to locate package update
```

Answer (score 1):

Press<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>, then enter the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install update
sudo startx
```

Try this